# Updating the version/revision numbers for every new build

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

To achieve CI/CD am using VSTS, now am stuck at a point where i am supposed to increase the version numbers for every new build queued.

Is it possible to update the revision number of each project outputs (dll's or exe's) just by adding one more task in build definition or any msbuild arguments are available to change the version numbers in run time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The new sdk-style project type supports msbuild parameters for that, but c# modification has to be done manually / via regexes (there also is [an extension for vsts](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sebastianlux.UpdateAssemblyInfo)), so it would help if state which project type you are using

Comment: Do you solve this issue with Chris's solution?

Comment: no starain i didn't get the chance to look into it.

Comment: What're steps you try it? Can you share the log on the OneDrive?

Answer (score 4):

BuildNumbers are automatically created against every build that gets scheduled.

You specify what you want this to be in the Build>Options>Build number format section.

Default value is:

```
$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)
```

But if you add some variables into your build then you can alter the format as such.

```
$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion)-$(date:MMdd)$(rev:.r)
```

This then get's passed through to your release step as the pre-defined variable

```
$[BUILD_BUILDNUMBER] - TFS 2010/15/17 Update1

$(Build.BuildNumber) changed from old $[BUILD_BUILDNUMBER] for Update2
```

More info on build numbers and variables can be found here:

[Build Number Format](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761520)

[Default Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?tabs=batch#default-variables)

Edits:

Yes you may add versioning to DLL's too. We use a a stock Microsoft Powershell script which does the trick, that we add as a build task (before the build solution step), the source can be found here:

[Assembly PowerShell Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/scripts/powershell)

This doesn't require any arguments as it uses the variables from the build process!

Comment: Thanks for giving the reply Chris. one more doubt , i am building a project the output of the project is dll, so is there any way to update the version number of the dll? by adding the task in build definition?

Comment: Edited the answer with more info on the DLL problem.

Comment: Chris one more doubt in my build definition i have multiple project files  instead of sln file so do i need to execute the powershell script before building every proj file

Comment: Hey Pavan, the powershell script just alters all the dll's that are present in your sources that you include in your first build process step. In my case the I built the solution afterwards with these values, you can then just build your project files as standard without adding the powershell script before every step

Comment: Hi Pavan, please accept the answer if this has helped, or let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Sure Chris i need sometime to try it i will let you know if any more questions are there.

Comment: Chris i have one more question please find it in the below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46486629/waiting-for-console-output-for-an-agent

Comment: i used updateassemblyinfo task which is an extension to update the version details instead of the powershell script

Comment: The script in the link was really plug-n-play for me, and I like having the flexibility of having the script in my repository as opposed to the extension.